# Finding location without moving, currently the best way?

Tags: android, gps

Is there any updated tutorial on how to get current location in Android applications? I have attempted any possible scenario i got across and i can't seem to find a solution for getting Android GPS locations. Routes that were suggested on many different posts with getLastKnownLocation() method, and with requestLocationUpdates(), always returned null references. So any suggestion on what practice is currently best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

requestLocationUpdates will return null if the location provider is turned off. It's usually best to check both `getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` and `lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)` to see if either one is not null.

Comment: Actually you solved my problem quite easily, because i intuitively thought GPS_PROVIDER is what i needed, checking both was the solution for me, thank you.